# Form convert to wrong json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a login form and I want to send a Post which contains a json.

Here is what I've done so far.

```
<form id="myForm">
    Login
    <input  id="login" type="text" name="login" value=""/>
    Password
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value=""/>
    <button type="submit" >Login</button>
</form>
```

and my js file

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    var frm = $("#myForm");
    var data = JSON.stringify(frm);

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/register/",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});
```

Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p143s6tp/

I expected json to look like this :

```
{ 
   "login" : "some_value",
   "password" : "some_value"
}
```

but I got this :

```
{"0":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{}},"length":1,"context":{"location":{}},"selector":"#myForm"}
```

I read some topics where people use .serializeArray() , but as a result I got array of single objects

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` on a jQuery object is going to stringify *the jQuery object*, not the data from the form elements.

Comment: As yourself noted, you have to use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) which returns array of names and values. Then you can convert it to desired format using Array's methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stringifying the form jQuery object returned by the selector `$("#myForm");`.

`.serializeArray()` would yield the output in the following format (name,value pairs),

```
[{"name":"login","value":"test"},{"name":"password","value":"test"}]
```

---

You can modify the output returned by `.serializeArray()`.

```
var frm = $("#myForm");
var formData = frm.serializeArray();
var data = {};
$.map(formData, function (obj,i) {
    data[obj['name']] = obj['value'];
});
```

Applying `JSON.stringify()` will yield:

> {"login":"test","password":"test"}

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p143s6tp/4/)**

Comment: One issue might be the OP *wants* to send the data in JSON format (although in reality it may need to be `x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I wrote this    var frm = $("#myForm").serialize(); and rest of code I left unchanged. As a result post look like this : "login=dsad&password=dsad" instead of json

Comment: I know that I can get an array of objects  ( as I wrote in my first post) , but I want to have a single object. I am using jackson which convert automatically it to my java objects, so I have to have the format described in my first post

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

**JS**

```
var login = $('#login').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/register/",
        data: {'login':login,'password':password},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

echo 'login:' . $login . ' - password: ' . $password;
```

Comment: In my application it's more complex object than the one I wrote in jsfiddle and it'd be nice to have a way to do it automatically, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    var frm = $("#myForm");
    var data = frm.serialize();

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/register/",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});
```

Comment: not work, as a result I get {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Answer (score 0):

As yourself noted, you have to use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). It  returns array of names and values which you can convert to desired format using Array's methods.

Something like this:

```
var data = {};
frm.serializeArray().forEach(function(el) {
    data[el.name] = el.value;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: not work. I don't know why but after submit is get instead of post

Comment: @Yeynno What is exactly "not work"? Provide detailed explanation

Comment: Very sorry, it also works fine. I think that jsfiddle cached previous code somehow or I did something wrong.